# How to use libFM under windows?

Tags: linux, recommendation-engine, factorization, matrix-factorization

Can anyone explain how to use `libFM` under windows, instead of under `Linux`?

I have downloaded `libFM` windows version, but clicking on the .exe files, there are windows popped out and then gone.

It will be great if someone can share the steps of using it under windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. From the libfm website (http://www.libfm.org/), download the
   windows executable and extract the zipped folder.
2. Now use cmd to navigate to the extracted files under the folder
   'libfm-1.40.windows' (this being the current version). Then, run the
   libfm command in cmd for executing the factorization machine with your train and test files. For example,

   libFM -task r -train trainfile.libfm -test testfile.libfm -dim ’1,1,8’

   with trainfile.libfm, testfile.libfm as the train and test files respectively. The format of the command is documented in the readme.pdf that gets extracted from the above downloaded folder.

The catch here is to drop the './' part (given in the readme.pdf) of the command when running it in windows. That's all. The program runs and you see the progress in the cmd.